# Find the value of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\{ (n+M)^\alpha -n^\alpha\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question about a sequence and its limit.

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $M>0$. I want to show
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \{(n+M)^{\alpha}-n^\alpha \}=0.
\end{align*}

**My attempt**

If $\alpha=1/2$, then $(n+M)^{1/2}-n^{1/2}=M/\{(n+M)^{1/2}+n^{1/2}\} \to 0.$

In genreal, using $t^\alpha \le t$ $(t \ge 1)$,
\begin{align*}
0 &\le (n+M)^\alpha -n^\alpha \\
&=n^\alpha \left(1+\frac{M}{n} \right)^\alpha- n^{\alpha} \\
&\le n^{\alpha} \left( 1+\frac{M}{n} \right) -n^{\alpha}\\
&=Mn^{\alpha-1} \to 0 \qquad (\text{ as } n \to \infty).
\end{align*}

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes it is, once you show $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is increasing on $[1,+\infty)$. Note that you should mention by what theorem you can conclude.

Comment: Is this fact related to anything?

Comment: Yes, it's called _squeeze theorem_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also could have used $$n^\alpha \left(1+\frac{M}{n} \right)^\alpha- n^{\alpha}= n^{\alpha}\left(\left(1+\frac{M}{n} \right)^\alpha-1\right)$$ and used the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) (or Taylor series)
$$\left(1+\frac{M}{n} \right)^\alpha=1+\frac{\alpha  M}{n}+\frac{(\alpha -1) \alpha  M^2}{2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which makes $$n^\alpha \left(1+\frac{M}{n} \right)^\alpha- n^{\alpha}=\alpha M n^{\alpha-1}+\cdots $$